# mysql query to count sellers and items at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm preparing for the SQL test (MySQL), and I have a problem with this task: having 2 tables, ITEMS and SELLERS, I need to prepare a table of the sellers based on the number of items they sell. Required output example:

```
num_sellers  items_offered
10           3
20           4
35           6
```

Schemas:

SELLERS has fields: id (unique seller id), name (name of the seller),

ITEMS has fields: id (unique item id), name (some name of the item), seller_id (id of the seller that sells this item).

Any ideas how to do it? I tried to use CTE for this, but my solution was rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(seller_id) as num_sellers,
    items_offered
FROM (
    SELECT
        seller_id,
        COUNT(id) as items_offered
    FROM
        items
    GROUP BY
        seller_id
) t
GROUP BY
    items_offered
ORDER BY
    items_offered
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It works! Thanks. I tested it in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0c7cc/1